# Spacy Installation error in python, with pip command

Tags: python, pip, spacy

Thanks for looking into this, I was trying to install spacy with python 3.8 ( I tried it with 3.7.9 interpreter too ) But apparently It has been giving me following errors. Command used
`pip install spacy`

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python38-32\python.exe' 
'c:\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 
'C:\Users\jayspc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1o6ows04\overlay'
--no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 
setuptools 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0'
'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0'
'thinc>=7.4.1,<7.5.0' 'numpy==1.15.0; python_version<='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; 
python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"'' 'numpy;
python_version>='"'"'3.10'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

can you please suggest me possible fixes ?

Comment: plase  add the log content

Comment: Also the command yiou used for installing

Comment: @PDHide I added the pip command and I was Installing this from windows powershell so about the log, I'm sorry could you please tell how that's done, I'm a python newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There may be a problem with your **pip** cache and/or your pip version:

Try this:

1. Delete your **pip** cache as it may appear to be causing troubles.

On windows it is located on:

`C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\pip\cache`

[image: Just delete the folder.]

2. Then update pip to the latest version for the installation to work,

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

3. After this process, try installing spaCy again:

`python -m pip install spacy`

or else, you could also try to Uninstall Python 32-bit and install Python-64 bit.

Comment: I did not work , it is still giving me errors

Comment: I did not try 64 bit , is amd64.exe is that a 64 bit version, python installation site doesn't seem to have explicitly mentioned 64 bit anywhere

Comment: If it still did not work, open your directory in [cmd](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and type:

$  python -m venv .env
$  .env\Scripts\activate
$  pip install -U spacy
$  python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

Comment: [64 Bit Installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/python-3.9.0-amd64.exe)


Check for other Windows versions [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Comment: You definitely need 64-bit python.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're in the wrong location, try `cd PIPLOCATIONHERE` and then (in Windows) `pip install spacy`. I'm not that sure but I guess you can try.